# How to store a method in a static variable?

Tags: python

I was looking for a way to dynamically add static methods to a python class.

My attempt was as following:

```
class C(object):
    a = None

k = 2
C.a = lambda x: k*x
print C.a(2)
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying that `C` instance is required as the first argument to `a`. Effectively, python thinks that `a` is an instance method of class `C` and not a class method.

What are the reasons for this? How can I overcome the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `staticmethod`:

```
>>> C.a = staticmethod(lambda x: k*x)
>>> print C.a(2)
4
```